# Falha no "git push origin development": non-fast-forward

Tags: git, bitbucket

Estou no desenvolvimento de um sistema e a situação é a seguinte: eu criei alguns arquivos novos na minha máquina e quero enviar para o Bitbucket mas não vai. Quando fui criando eu fui dando commits, mas, meu colega no desenvolvimento, deu outros commits e enviou para o Bitbucket antes de mim, que tenho commits mais novos e mais velhos que os commits dele
Quando dou o comando `git push origin development`, aparece a seguinte mensagem:

```
! [rejected]        development -> development (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://[...]/migration.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Executo `git status` e fala que não há nada para dar commit.
Executo `git pull origin development` e fala que tudo já está atualizado.
Estou usando o Bitbucket. Será que tenho que enviar os novos arquivos para o servidor de forma manual?

Comment: já tentou git pull origin development ?

Comment: Já tentei... Ele fala que está tudo atualizado

Comment: já tentou forçar com git push origin --force ?

Comment: Usei o --force mas não estou achando o código no bitbucket. Parece que não foi...

Comment: você tinha commits pra subir? seu git status ainda mostra alguma coisa?

Comment: Quando executo `git status` aparece:`On branch migration_code_wandre_oo
Your branch and 'origin/migration_code_wandre_oo' have diverged,
and have 21 and 2 different commits each, respectively.
  (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: tente git pull origin migration_code_wandre_oo e depois tente fazer um push do seus commits

Comment: Não sei porque mas agora deu.
Os comandos que executei foram:
`git pull origin migration_code_wandre_oo`
`git status`
`git branch` (confirmei que estava na branch migration_code_wandre_oo)
`git pull` (abriu o nano e dei control+x)
`git push` (agora os arquivos foram realmente enviados ao Bitbucket)
Muito obrigado @GeiltonXavier

Comment: Legal, acredito que o problema é que você estava tratando sua branch  migration_code_wandre_oo com o nome errado, percebi quando vc me enviou o resultado do git status. que bom que resolveu.